# How to read console log output in protractor?

Tags: protractor

Console output:

```
8 specs, 5 failures
Finished in 105.229 seconds
```

I want to read above console output and store it in some file.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your conf.js file. See if you are using a reporter plugin or not. 
If you are, remove it to get all the logs or modify it to display what you want.

You could just redirect the ouput of protractor to a file with "> file.txt" or ">> file.txt"